# Forwarding data between two interfaces

Tags: dhcp

I installed Ubuntu server 12.04 after that I installed dhcp3-server and configured it like this:

At **isc-dhcp-server**

```
INTERFACES="eth0"
```

And in **dhcpd.conf**

```
# A slightly different configuration for an internal subnet.
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.1.5 192.168.1.100;
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1;
  option domain-name "nazwa.local";
  option routers 192.168.1.1;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
  default-lease-time 600;
  max-lease-time 7200;
}
```

Also I have two eth interfaces:

```
# second netowrk interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0

# The primary network interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

When I plug computer to eth0 I get propertly ip adress but I can't visit any sites. I do even this:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 10.0.0.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    up /sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -d 0/0 -j MASQUERADE
```

And everything worked!